# Java application not able to receive UDP packets over internet

Tags: java, android, networking, udp, arduino

I have set up a program for Arduino to receive UDP packets and send a simple response to those packets. For some reason my Android application isn't able to receive the response over the public internet. If I connect my phone with WLAN my application receives the response. In all cases Arduino is able to receive these packets sent by Android because I have assigned a port forwarder for this port.

I have also checked my ISP's website for possible port restrictions. My wired connection at home where Arduino is connected has a public IP with no restrictions on that port. My mobile broadband connection provider doesn't have restrictions on that port either but they are using NAT for mobile connections. Might this be a problem?

On Android I have the following code:

```
byte[] data = ("data").getBytes();

try {
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, arduinoAddress, arduinoPort);

    socket.send(packet);

    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1];
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    socket.receive(receivePacket);

    System.out.println(new String(receivePacket.getData()));
} catch(InterruptedIOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

    return 2;
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Arduino has this:

```
void loop() {
    int packetSize = UDP.parsePacket();

    if(packetSize) {
        UDP.read(packetBuffer, UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE);
        String data = String(packetBuffer);

        for(int i = 0; i < UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE; i++) {
          packetBuffer[i] = 0;
        }

        Serial.println(data);

        UDP.beginPacket(UDP.remoteIP(), UDP.remotePort());
        UDP.print("1");
        UDP.endPacket();

        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Whan NAT is used you have to forward the UDP packets to the originating device. I doubt that mobile providers do this.

Therefore using UDP to get replies from the internet in mobile environments will be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

There is much information on this topic.  The search word you are looking for is "hole punching" or "UDP hole punching".

[Of course a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching)

[A StackOverflow for good measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557691/udp-hole-punching-one-symmitric-and-another-non-symmetric-nat)

I have similar question as you.  Along the lines of how to connect my mobile phone and a small device, I am looking for something part way between Twitter and a chat service.  How do you send small private messages, but only point to point?